# Show that a random variable is integrable

Tags: integration, probability-theory, improper-integrals, expected-value

If $X$ is a random variable such that $X \geq 0$ a.s., I've been told that $$Xe^{-tX}$$ is an integrable random variable, ($t>0$). But why?

By definition, I should checl that $$E[X e^{-tX}] < \infty$$

Now, the integral is equal to $\int_0^\infty x e^{-tx}f(x)dx$ where $f$ is the density function of $X$.

How can I show it's integrable?

**Edit**

Since $e^x \geq x$, then $e^{-tx} \leq \frac{1}{tx}$.

Hence the integrand function is bounded in this way: $$x e^{-tx} f(x) \leq \frac{1}{t} f(x)$$

Now I know that $\int_0^\infty t f(x) dx = t \cdot 1$ (as $f$ is a density) and hence $X e^{-tX}$ is an integrable random variable, as it's bounded by an integrable random variable.

Comment: Do you know that $e^x\ge x$ for all $x\ge0$?

Comment: @kimchilover Brilliant hint!

Comment: Yes, but how can this help?

Comment: so $e^{-x} \leq \frac{1}{x}$ ? But at $x=0$ I have problems..

Comment: It implies $e^{-tx}\leq \ldots$. Please fill in the gap!

Comment: A bounded random variable is integrable. (The total measure is one, finite.)

Comment: @dan_fulea how can it be bounded? Do I have to assume that the density functions is bounded, rtight?

Comment: I'm editing my question with a possible solution using @kimchilover hint

Comment: I've edited my answer, could you please tell me if everything is okay now? Thanks for the time

Comment: But that's because you're implicitely using the theorem that says that if the random variable is bounded, then it's integrable. That's fine for me. BUT I want to show it using the right formula for the expectation

Comment: Is my reasoning okay?

Comment: It does not cover, eg, the Binomial random variable, which does not _have_ a density function.

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^{x}\geq x$ for $x>0$ you have $e^{-tx}\leq\frac{1}{tx}$, thus $xe^{-tx}\leq \frac{1}{t}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: so since the integrand is bounded by a constant ($\frac{1}{t}$), then it's integrable, right?

Comment: @andereBen You've checked that $\mathbb{E}(Xe^{-tX})\leq \frac{1}{t}$ which is $<\infty$ since $t>0$